# How to create pyral configuration file in rally development?

Tags: python, rally, pyral

I am trying to use python REST API to access the contents from Rally. In read me, they mentioned to use a configuration file for server name, user credentials, etc. Where can i create a configuration file and what are the contents that i need to put in that configuration file.

Please help me... Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a config file when running a program using pyral, use the --conf= argument syntax on the command line. Note that you do not need to specify the '.cfg' suffix portion of your configuration file name.

Also, pyral offers some fairly lenient syntax when specifying the --conf part. You can also use --config=... or --cfg=... or --rallyConfig=... in addition to the --conf=... syntax.

Within your Python script using pyral, you'll need to import rallySettings and have some code containing variable definitions, etc. Here's an example of the calling sequence that uses the contents of a config file named sample.conf:

```
python test_prog.py --conf=sample
```

sample.conf:

```
 SERVER    = rally1.rallydev.com  
 USER      = your_Rally_user_name@your_company.com
 PASSWORD  = your_Rally_password
 WORKSPACE = Your Rally Workspace 
 PROJECT   = Your Rally Project
```